# RAM test steps through, but fails when running

Tags: c, testing, embedded, ram, pic

The project I'm working on has to test the data memory of a dsPIC30F chip before the program runs. Due to industry requirements, we cannot utilize any pre-defined libraries that C has to offer. That being said, here is my methodology for testing the RAM:

```
Step 1 - Write the word 0xAAAA to a specific location in memory (defined by a LoopIndex added to the START_OF_RAM address)

Step 2 - increment LoopIndex

Step 3 - Repeat Steps 1-2 until LoopIndex + START_OF_RAM >= END_OF_RAM

Step 4 - Reset LoopIndex = 0

Step 5 - Read memory at LoopIndex+START_OF_RAM

Step 6 - If memory = 0xAAAA, continue, else throw RAM_FAULT_HANDLER

Step 7 - increment LoopIndex

Step 8 - Repeat Step 5 - 7 until LoopIndex + START_OF_RAM >= END_OF_RAM
```

Now, the weird part is that I can step through the code, no problem. It will slowly loop through each memory address for as long as my little finger can press F8, but as soon as I try to set up a breakpoint at Step 4, it throws a random, generic interrupt handler for no apparent reason. I've thought that it could be due to the fact that the `for()` I use may exceed END_OF_RAM, but I've changed the bounds of the conditions and it still doesn't like to run.

Any insight would be helpful.

```
void PerformRAMTest()
{

    // Locals
    uint32_t LoopIndex = 0;
    uint16_t *AddressUnderTest;
    uint32_t RAMvar = 0;
    uint16_t i = 0;

    // Loop through RAM and write the first pattern (0xAA) - from the beginning to the first RESERVED block
    for(LoopIndex = 0x0000; LoopIndex < C_RAM_END_ADDRESS; LoopIndex+= 2)
    {

        AddressUnderTest = (uint32_t*)(C_RAM_START_ADDRESS + LoopIndex);

        *AddressUnderTest = 0xAAAA;


    }// end for

    for(LoopIndex = 0x0000; LoopIndex < C_RAM_END_ADDRESS; LoopIndex += 2)
    {
        AddressUnderTest = (uint32_t*)(C_RAM_START_ADDRESS + LoopIndex);

        if(*AddressUnderTest != 0xAAAA)
            {
                // If what was read does not equal what was written, log the
                // RAM fault in NVM and call the RAMFaultHandler()
                RAMFaultHandler();
            }// end if
    }

    // Loop through RAM and write then verify the second pattern (0x55)
    // - from the beginning to the first RESERVED block
//    for(LoopIndex = C_RAM_START_ADDRESS; LoopIndex < C_RAM_END_ADDRESS; LoopIndex++)
//    {
//        AddressUnderTest = (uint32_t*)(C_RAM_START_ADDRESS + LoopIndex);
//        *AddressUnderTest = 0x5555;
//        if(*AddressUnderTest != 0x5555)
//        {
//            // If what was read does not equal what was written, log the
//            // RAM fault in NVM and call the RAMFaultHandler()
//            RAMFaultHandler();
//        }
//    }

}// end PerformRAMTest
```

You can see that the second pass of the test writes `0x55`. This was the original implementation that was given to me, but it never worked (at least as far as debugging/running; the same random interrupt was encountered with this method of writing then immediately reading the same address before moving on)

**UPDATE**: After a few Clean&Builds, the code will now run through until it hits the stack pointer (WREG15), skip over, then errors out. Here is a new sample of the code in question:

```
if(AddressUnderTest >= &SPLIMIT && AddressUnderTest <= SPLIMIT)
    {
        // if true, set the Loop Index to point to the end of the stack
        LoopIndex = (uint16_t)SPLIMIT;
    }
    else if(AddressUnderTest == &SPLIMIT) // checkint to see if AddressUnderTest points directly to the stack [This works while the previous >= &SPLIMIT does not. It will increment into the stack, update, THEN say "oops, I just hit the stack" and error out.]
    {
        LoopIndex = &SPLIMIT;
    }
    else
    {
        *AddressUnderTest = 0xAAAA;
    }
```

Comment: Where in memory is your program and your stack?

Comment: Shouldn't you be casting `(C_RAM_START_ADDRESS + LoopIndex)` to `(uint16_t*)`?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - DATA Memory should theoretically start at 0x0800, the Program memory starts, well, we don't know. We know the W15 register is the Stack Pointer, and we have a variable SPLIMIT that I've tried to verify and enable LoopIndex to skip over, however, that didn't work either.

Comment: @Magtheridon96 - Theoretically, yes, however, total RAM goes to 0x17FFE, and, again, this is based on code that was given to me.

Comment: So, you may be writing over the program instructions/data/stack while it's running? That can't end well.

Comment: @Casey That's the thought, but when I put in a test `if()` to see if I can get through two iterations of the loop, it still halts. Wait... now it's working... I can get from 0x0800 to 0x1D00 without issue, but going beyond that... I think I may be running into the stack.

Comment: Which dsPIC30F are you using (e.g. - dsPIC30F1010)?  I am interested in looking at the data memory map to see if I can help, but it is device specific.

Comment: @embedded_guy - dsPIC30F6012A ;

I've looked at the Data Memory map and I can't make heads or tails out of it. I was told to just use the pointers they had been using on other projects, and I've finally been able to get it to loop through, to some degree. I'll post an update, shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually want `(C_RAM_START_ADDRESS + LoopIndex) < C_RAM_END_ADDRESS` as your loop condition. Currently, you are looping from `C_RAM_START_ADDRESS` to `C_RAM_START_ADDRESS + C_RAM_END_ADDRESS` which I assume is writing past the end of the RAM.

You also should really factor out the repeated code into a separate function that takes the test pattern as a parameter ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

Comment: I've changed `LoopIndex < C_RAM_END_ADDRESS` to `(C_RAM_START_ADDRESS + LoopIndex) < C_RAM_END_ADDRESS` and the program still halts. 


Also, I previously split the write and read functions into two different `for()` loops to test a theory that the issue we were having was due to a race condition for reading after the write. Nope, still doesn't work after splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so there are a number of things that we can look at to get a better understanding of where your problem may be.  There are some things that I would like to point out - and hopefully we can figure this out together.  The first thing that I noticed that seems a little out of place is this comment:

> "...total RAM goes to 0x17FFE..."

I looked up the data sheet for the [dsPIC30F6012A](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70143E.pdf) .  You can see in Figure 3-8 (pg. 33), that the SRAM space is 8K and runs from 0x0800 to 0x2800.  Also, there is this little tidbit:

> "All effective addresses are 16 bits wide and point to bytes within the data space"

So, you can use 16 bit values for your addresses.  I am a little confused by your update as well.  `SPLIM` is a register that you set the value for - and that value limits the size of your stack.  I'm not sure what the value for your `SPLIMIT` is, but `W15` is your actual stack pointer register, and the value that is stored there is the address to the top of your stack:

> "There is a Stack Pointer Limit register (SPLIM) associated
>   with the Stack Pointer. SPLIM is uninitialized at
>   Reset. As is the case for the Stack Pointer, SPLIM<0>
>   is forced to ‘0’ because all stack operations must be
>   word aligned. **Whenever an Effective Address (EA) is
>   generated using W15 as a source or destination
>   pointer, the address thus generated is compared with
>   the value in SPLIM. If the contents of the Stack Pointer
>   (W15) and the SPLIM register are equal and a push
>   operation is performed, a Stack Error Trap will not
>   occur.**"

Finally, the stack grows from the lowest available SRAM address value up to `SPLIM`.  So I would propose setting the `SPLIM` value to something reasonable, let's say 512 bytes (although it would be best to [test how much room you need for your stack](http://www.iar.com/Global/Resources/Developers_Toolbox/Building_and_debugging/Mastering_stack_and_heap_for_system_reliability.pdf)).

Since this particular stack grows upwards, I would start at 0x0800 plus what we added for the stack limit and then test from there (which would be 0x1000).  This way you won't have to worry about your stack region.

Given the above, here is how I would go about doing this.

```
void PerformRAMTest (void)
{
    #define SRAM_START_ADDRESS  0x0800

    /* Stack size = 512 bytes.  Assign STACK_LIMIT
       to SPLIM register during configuration. */
    #define STACK_SIZE          0x0200

    /* -2, see pg 35 of dsPIC30F6012A datasheet. */
    #define STACK_LIMIT             ((SRAM_START_ADDRESS + STACK_SIZE) - 2)
    #define SRAM_BEGIN_TEST_ADDRESS ((volatile uint16_t *)(STACK_LIMIT + 2))
    #define SRAM_END_TEST_ADDRESS   0x2800
    #define TEST_VALUE              0xAAAA

    /* No need for 32 bit address values on this platform */
    volatile uint16_t * AddressUnderTest = SRAM_BEGIN_TEST_ADDRESS

    /* Write to memory */
    while (AddressUnderTest < SRAM_END_TEST_ADDRESS)
    {
        *AddressUnderTest = TEST_VALUE;
        AddressUnderTest++;
    }

    AddressUnderTest = SRAM_BEGIN_TEST_ADDRESS;

    /* Read from memory */
    while (AddressUnderTest < SRAM_END_TEST_ADDRESS)
    {
        if (*AddressUnderTest != TEST_VALUE)
        {
            RAMFaultHandler();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            AddressUnderTest++;
        }
    }
}
```

My code was a bit rushed so I am sure there are probably some errors (feel free to edit), but hopefully this will help get you on the right track!

Comment: This helps quite a lot, and it works, for the most part. I'm currently debugging it to see where it errors out, but it's definitely much more concise coding that I originally had.

Comment: So, I've done some more digging and `SPLIMIT` is, in fact, `SPLIM` just defined manually in another IOMap file. I'll see about taking it out of the code and just using `SPLIM` from here on out.

Comment: @ThomSirveaux Out of curiousity, did you ever get this to work?

Comment: I think so. I actually can't remember, due in large part to leaving that job and finally becoming a full fledged Electrical Engineer. :)

Comment: @ThomSirveaux Fair enough.  I was just curious.

Comment: No worries. I've been trying to remember what happened, and I think it was actually fixed by another SW Eng in my department.